# Admob banner wrong position

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, banner

I have a android game written with JAVA, for some unknown reason, Admob banner is displayed in wrong position on small percentage of our players devices, I have already tested it on 30+ devices, but could not reproduce it, some players sent us proofs though.

By design, our banner should ALWAYS be displayed in TOP RIGHT corner of the screen, but sometimes its getting displayed in TOP LEFT, any idea will be greatly appreciated.

That's how I initialise it (I am doing everything programatically, no xml's

```
    @Override
    protected void onSetContentView()
    {
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
        this.mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(this.mEngine, this);

        final android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
        surfaceViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        relativeLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams fparams=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        adView = new AdView(this);

        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams adViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.END | Gravity.TOP);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("....");
        adView.setEnabled(false);
        adView.refreshDrawableState();
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.GONE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.refreshDrawableState();

        frameLayout.addView(adView,adViewLayoutParams);

        relativeLayout.addView(frameLayout,fparams);

        this.setContentView(relativeLayout, relativeLayoutLayoutParams);
    }
```

Show/hide methods:

```
public void hideBanner()
    {
        if (adDisplayed)
        {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adView.setEnabled(false);
                    adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    adDisplayed = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void showBanner()
    {
        if (!ResourcesManager.getInstance().isNoAdverts())
        {
            if (!adDisplayed)
            {
                this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

                        adView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded()
                            {
                                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                adView.setEnabled(true);
                                adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                        adDisplayed = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my project settings:

```
    compileSdkVersion 28
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

This issue was reported from players with SDK: 23

Comment: Do you know which API version the users experiencing the problem are on? What is your minimum SDK version? It seems like an issue with `Gravity.END`, but there isn't enough info for me to be sure.

Comment: Hi Leo, I have added those details in the bottom of my post, thank you!

Comment: Are the users experiencing the problem using a right-to-left language (like Hebrew)?

Comment: @BenP - yes, it was reported by user from Israel . Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the problem was reported by a user in Israel, I suspect that the user has their device's language set to a *right-to-left* language, like Hebrew.

Since you are using `Gravity.END`, this will place the element on the left side of the device in this scenario (since, after all, that *is* the "end" for this user). If you want the element to always be on the right, regardless of the normal layout direction for your user's chosen language, build your `LayoutParams` with `Gravity.RIGHT` instead.

Alternatively, you could disable [right-to-left support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#supportsrtl) for your application. Check the `<application>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and delete this attribute:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Comment: Hi Ben, that actually makes sense (I used to have gravity RIGHT, and recently updated it to END when i switched networks) I will change that, upload updated apk to the play store, and ask admob team to review my violation, and I will get back to mark this answer as correct hopefully, thank you!